# Activity makeSceneTransitionAnimation and reverse like Gmail App

Tags: android, animation, gmail

Scenario:

In Gmail app Android Lollipop , when user select a mail at mail list screen, it will go to detail and perform expand animation at selected item. At detail screen, user can swipe left or right to view next/previous mail and when user press back, it will reverse animation at selected item to position on mail list.

In case if user swipe to view mail that was visible at mail list screen, it will animate to bottom.

So, my question is "How to can do like that?"

Answer (score 3):

It is functionality comes in lollipop called as **shared element transition** and you can achieve it by placing the same transition name on the component and share with next fragment.

Here is a good example for you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/103367/material-design